# database base values in WTForms without submitting

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am trying to develop a WTForm where users can select one or many part numbers in a table. After the user enters a part number I want to show the master data associated to it (right next to the part number). Such as weight, price etc., rendered in the same template. An SQLIte Table is holding the master data for all part numbers.
At the end, the intention is to sum up the values (price, weight) in a seperate line for the part numbers entered in the WTForm list.

All I find in documentation for WTForm processing is related to "on_submit". But users will never submit the form. 
I believe I do not have the right implementation approach right now. First, my current coding is not updating the values in the form, second I dont want to have a submit button in order to see the content_values.

```
class kundenanalyse_items(FlaskForm):
ka_fm = SelectField('Futtermittel', choices=[('a', 'a Wert'), ('b', 'b 
Wert'), ('17', 'irgendwas')])
ka_fm_menge = IntegerField('g/Tag (Tagesplan) bzw. g/Woche (Wochenplan)')
ka_fm_content01 = IntegerField('ka_fm_content01')
ka_fm_content02 = DecimalField('ka_fm_content02')

@app.route('/kundenanalyse', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def kundenanalyse():
ka_line01 = kundenanalyse_items()

if request.method == 'POST':
    flash('Daten an DB gesendet {} : {} + {} : 
{}'.format(ka_line01.ka_fm.data, ka_line01.ka_fm_menge.data, 
ka_line02.ka_fm.data))
    ka_line01.ka_fm_content01.data = '100' * ka_line01.ka_fm_menge.data
ka_line01.ka_fm_content02.data = '200' * ka_line01.ka_fm_menge.data
    return redirect(url_for('kundenanalyse'))

return render_template('kundenanalyse.html', ka_line01=ka_line01)

kundenanlyse.html:
{% extends 'layout.html' %}
{% block body %}
{% for message in get_flashed_messages() %}
<div class=flash style="color: orangered;">
    {{ message }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
<form method="POST", action="/kundenanalyse")>
<div class="tg-wrap"><table class="tg" style="undefined;">
 <tr>
<th class="tg-wh92">{{ ka_line01.ka_fm.label }}</th>
<th class="tg-wh92">{{ ka_line01.ka_fm_menge.label }}</th>
<th class="tg-wh92">{{ ka_line01.ka_fm_content01.label }}</th>
<th class="tg-wh92">{{ ka_line01.ka_fm_content02.label }}</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-e3ma">{{ ka_line01.ka_fm }}</td>
<td class="tg-sh4c">{{ ka_line01.ka_fm_menge }}</td>
<td class="tg-hkz2">{{ ka_line01.ka_fm_content01 }}</td>
<td class="tg-hkz2">{{ ka_line01.ka_fm_content02 }}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

thank you in advance.
Michael

Comment: If you can add code to highlight what you currently have it might help you to get better answers. For help on asking questions see the ['How do I ask a good question'](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Comment: sorry, added some more details now (in a comprimated way)